# Does NY State have a cap of seven casinos?

Tags: new-york-state, constitutional-law, gambling

According to [Ars Technica's quote of the NY Constitution](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/11/ny-has-a-lottery-but-says-online-fantasy-sports-are-an-illegal-lottery/), it states in part:

> [E]xcept as hereinafter provided, no lottery or the sale of lottery tickets, pool-selling, book-making, or any other kind of gambling, except lotteries operated by the state..., except pari-mutuel betting on horse races..., *and except casino gambling at no more than seven facilities...*, shall hereafter be authorized or allowed within this state; and the legislature shall pass appropriate laws to prevent offenses against any of the provisions of this section.

However, I could not find the italicized text, nor even the word 'casino,' in the [New York State Constitution as posted on the NY Department of State](https://www.dos.ny.gov/info/constitution.htm), "As Amended and in Force Since January 1, 2014."  Is Ars Technica getting a constitutional quote wrong*, or is there basis for it?

---

(*): Other than, possibly, the quoted spelling of [parimutuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parimutuel_betting), which may be an error in the constitution.  Even within the constitution as linked to, the title and text disagrees with the table of contents, so there seems to be at least one spelling error in there.

Answer (score 2):

Note first that Ars Technica is quoting from [a cease-and-desist letter](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/AGdraftkings.pdf) sent by the Office of the Attorney General of New York State.  So we really should hope that it's accurate.

Indeed, the quote is correct, and the HTML New York Constitution on the NY Department of State site is out of date.  The "seven facilities" clause was inserted as an amendment by the [New York Casino Gambling Amendment, Proposal 1 (2013)](https://ballotpedia.org/New_York_Casino_Gambling_Amendment,_Proposal_1_%282013%29), passed by voters in November 2013.  It also appears in the [PDF version of the Constitution](https://www.dos.ny.gov/info/pdfs/Constitution.pdf) linked from the previously mentioned HTML page; it's in Article I, Section 9. Prior to this amendment, casino gambling was entirely prohibited in the state.

The HTML version is dated January 1, 2014; the PDF version is dated January 1, 2015.  I would have guessed that an amendment passed in November 2013 would have become effective on January 1, 2014, and so should already have been included in the 2014 edition; but perhaps I am wrong.